# "entity.Attributes.Contains" method never returns true

Tags: c#, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Trying to create the CRM plugin on incident entity update event.

Here is a full code of plugin

```
namespace MyPluginPackage.Plugins{
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;

public class PreValidateCaseUpdate: Plugin
{
    public PreValidateCaseUpdate()
        : base(typeof(PreValidateCaseUpdate))
    {
        base.RegisteredEvents.Add(new Tuple<int, string, string, Action<LocalPluginContext>>(10, "Update", "incident", new Action<LocalPluginContext>(ExecutePreValidateCaseUpdate)));
    }

    protected void ExecutePreValidateCaseUpdate(LocalPluginContext localContext)
    {
        if (localContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("localContext");
        }

        IPluginExecutionContext context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;
        IOrganizationService service = localContext.OrganizationService;
        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
        context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity && context.Depth < 2)
        {
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
            try
            {

                if (entity.Attributes.Contains("customerid"))
                {
                    //Some code. For example updates incident entity description
                    entity["description"] = "Some description";
                }

                service.Update(entity);
            }
            catch (FaultException ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occurred in the plug-in.", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Problem is **if (entity.Attributes.Contains("customerid"))** never returns TRUE. "customerid" is a standart attribute of the incident entity. Any ideas and suggestions are very appreciated.

The method of deploying plugin which I use is described 
[in this blog post:](http://mscrmshop.blogspot.ru/2012/01/step-by-step-plugin-tutorial-using.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update of what field invokes plugin execution? In case customerid was not updated - it would not be present in Target, so you should use Images. I believe I already wrote it on other forum...

Comment: Thanks. Registering PreImage Alias helps.